# Redundant div using Backbone LayoutManager

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, backbone.js

I modified the **list.html** example here https://github.com/tbranyen/backbone.layoutmanager/blob/master/examples/list.html a bit:

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/nQJz6/

If you look into Firebug, you can see there is an extra `div` between `ol` and `li`.

I know I can get rid of it by moving `li` out the template and use `tagName: 'li'` in `Items` view. But that means I have to change my code in places. Also I prefer to keep the `li` in the template for **design process consistency**.

**How to get rid of this `div` without modifying the template?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Override the `partial` function and do a `jQuery#find` like so:

```
Backbone.LayoutManager.configure({
    partial: function(root, name, el, append) {
        // If no selector is specified, assume the parent should be added to.
        var $root = name ? $(root).find(name) : $(root);

        // Use the append method if append argument is true.
        // Set the element to append to be the first child.
        this[append ? "append" : "html"]($root, $(el).children().first());
    }
});
```

This method can be overwritten on a global (above) or local instance.

You will also need to adjust `afterRender` to use the new element:

```
Backbone.LayoutView.extend({
    afterRender: function() {
        this.setElement(this.el.firstChild);
        this.delegateEvents();
    }
});
```

More information here: http://tbranyen.github.com/backbone.layoutmanager/#configuration/defaults

Comment: Yah even with that fix, events still don't work: http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/nQJz6/1/

Comment: According to tbranyen on separate chat, there is no work around. Closing this one now.